# HTML5 Video Responsive with custom height

Tags: html, css

I'm having an issue with HTML5 video, width should be 100% and height 60vh (video needs to be displayed full and not stretched) .

I have tried with `position:absolute` and `padding:56%` but seems that doesn't work

```
<div class="item video-one">
      <video id="f-video" class="slide-video slide-media" autoplay="true" loop muted preload="metadata" >
        <source src="<?php the_field('video_url_future_living'); ?>?s=8a71ff38f08ec81efe50d35915afd426765a7526&profile_id=112" type="video/mp4" />
      </video>
    </div>
```

CSS Case 1 -> Doesn't work because it's cropping the video

```
.item {
    top: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100vw;
    max-width: 100%;
}
.item video {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

CSS Case 2 -> Doesn't work, it's full height and it's too much.

```
.item {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  padding-top: 30px;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.item video { 
 position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: have you tried 'position: relative; width: 100%; max-height: 60vh;'?

Comment: @VelimirTchatchevsky for CASE 1 or CASE 2?

Comment: just that, without absolute positioning, crazy padding or anything else, just the things you need

Comment: (after reading the edit) does the video need to be 100%, or does it need to keep the original aspect ratio, while having height 60vh?

Comment: @VelimirTchatchevsky Yes, I have tried but in this case, video is displayed not fully.

Comment: @VelimirTchatchevsky Yes, the video need to be 100% in width, but height should not be 100vh, because when i set height:100vh it works. I don't need height:100vh, just width, and video to be displayed fully on those dimensions

Comment: so you don't have any fixed height requirement, just not to be over 100vh? A fiddle example would really help btw

Comment: @VelimirTchatchevsky Hmm, height must be fixed, 60vh should be.

Comment: If you have fixed height, and fixed width, then the video will stretch or shrink according to the fixed dimensions, that's the expected behavior

Comment: @VelimirTchatchevsky Right, so there is no any solution to fix that?

Comment: well that's a popular paradox in web UI, you can only set one of the dimensions to a fixed value, you leave the other one responsive (eg. auto) because it needs that flexibility to keep the original aspect ratio. Setting two fixed values would naturally distort it, so you can only set one and keep the ratio. It's not about css, you'll have the same problem resizing any picture to fixed dimensions

Comment: @VelimirTchatchevsky OK. Thanks buddy.